# Sum all specific column value in DataGridView

Tags: mysql, database, datagridview, foreach, wamp

I'm using wamp, in which I'm running my own database and now I need to sum up all values of the specific column in all rows

Column name is "money"

I have tried the foreach loop but it gave me an error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{   
      allMoney += int.Parse(row.Cells["money"].Value.ToString());                  
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Are you sure, that you have a column named "money" in the DataGridView? Try setting a breakpoint in the loop and watch for row.Cells["money"]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes I'm sure it's name is money, checked with breakpoint, the value of the cell is correct, but still it give me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged MySQL so lets answer this from a database point of view.

In your query you need to use SUM() to add up the values of each row.

e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(order_value) FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to sum up values, not the rows, in your example I think it would be useful if I wanted to count rows? Or it will work with values too?

Comment: @user2013456 sorry this was a typo, it should have said SUM. I've now edited it.

Comment: Oh now I understand, I was thinking about that kind of workaround, thanks again :)